# Getting all values from checkboxes and saving them to SQL Server in one row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, checkbox, groupbox

I am trying to develop a Windows form application using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2014.

My question is about getting the values of chechkboxes that are checked, and saving all data to one row in SQL Server.

Example:

`TBL_EXAMPLE`:

```
               ID int PK not null,
               NAME nvarchar(max) null
```

I have 3 checkboxes in my program:

```
checkbox1 - name : chkbx1   checked
checkbox2 - name : chkbx2   checked 
checkbox3 - name : chkbx3   not checked
```

I need to add values of checkboxes to one column called name in SQL Server

After adding SQL Server content of NAME should be like this:

```
 NAME
 checkbox1 checkbox2
```

I tried to write like this:

```
foreach (Control cont in this.groupBox1.Controls)
{
    if (cont is CheckBox)
    {
       if (((CheckBox)cont).Checked == true)
       {
           sqlcon.Open();
           SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES ( '" + ((CheckBox)cont).Text.ToString() + "')", sqlcon);
           sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           sqlcon.Close();
           MessageBox.Show("OK");
       }
    }
}
```

It gave results like this:

```
ID       NAME
1         checkbox1
2         checkbox2
```

I want to see this:

```
ID        NAME
1         checkbox1 checkbox2
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the strings in your loop and then finally insert the concatenated string.

```
List<string> checks = new List<string>();
foreach (Control cont in this.groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        if (cont is CheckBox)

        {

            if (((CheckBox)cont).Checked == true)
            {
                checks.Add(((CheckBox)cont).Text);
            }


        }
    }

sqlcon.Open();
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES ( '" + string.Join(" ",checks) + "')", sqlcon);
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcon.Close();
MessageBox.Show("OK");
```

Comment: gives me result like this;  1 checkbox2   2 checkbox2 checkbox1

Comment: @SelçukAYDIN When you check 2 checkboxes, how many elements do you see in your debug window for the variable `checks`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to compose a string with the checked checkboxes and write the result in the table. Here's a (non optimal) solution. I say "non optimal" because I would personally prefer to use parameters, but I prefer not to change too much so you get the point:

```
StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Control cont in this.groupBox1.Controls)
{
    if (cont is CheckBox)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)cont).Checked == true)
        {
            name.Append(((CheckBox)cont).Text.ToString() + " ");
        }
    }
}

sqlcon.Open();
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_EXAMPLE VALUES ( '" + name.ToString().Trim() + "')", sqlcon);
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcon.Close();
MessageBox.Show("OK");
```